# (0,react.memo) is not a function.(in '(0,_react.memo)(FastimageBase)')'),'(0,_react.memo)' is undefined)

Tags: react-native

I use expo to open my react native project expo and get this error appeared:

> `(0,react.memo) is not a function.(in '(0,_react.memo) 
>    (FastimageBase)','(0,_react.memo)' is undefined)'`

[image]

this is my npm packages`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "^1.1.2",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "expokit": "^32.0.7",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "qs": "^6.6.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-moment": "^0.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.0"
  }
```

Comment: Have you get any solution ?

Comment: Did anyone got solution to this?